# Separating items into a 3d ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D `List` of type `Integer` (`ArrayList< List < Integer > >`),
There are currently **177147 lists of integers**.
I want to separate these into 243 different collections (Each collection having 729 lists of elements)

e.g. `Array[0] -> Array[728] go into Collection[0]`

...until 
     `Array[176417] -> Array[177146] goes into Collection[242]`

Should I rather use `ArrayList<ArrayList<List<Integer>>>`?
If so, how do I separate these items in this manner?

Comment: You haven't given enough information for anyone to advise usefully. Why do you want to split up the lists? What are your criteria for splitting? Why 243 lists of 729?  Do you need to modify the lists at all? (if no, then maybe you should use arrays instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate on the elements and add by slices to the new structure:

```
public void run() {
    int SLICE = 729;
    List<List<Integer>> list2d = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    // fill original list
    List<List<List<Integer>>> list3d = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();
    List<List<Integer>> partial = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(SLICE);
    for (List<Integer> list : list2d) {
        partial.add(list);
        if (partial.size() == SLICE) {
            list3d.add(partial);
            partial = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(SLICE);
        }
    }
    if (!partial.isEmpty()) {
        list3d.add(partial);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This along with cloning the arraylist worked!

Comment: Code fixed to avoid reusing partial array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int c = 0; c <= 242; c++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 729; i++)
    {
        int position = (c * 729) + i;
        Collection[c][i] = Array[position];
    }
}
```

You might want to check my maths on the formula for position, but the idea is sound.